# What is µMAX IC package?

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages

While ordering free samples from Maxim I have often seen components packaged as *µMAX*.

What is µMAX?  When googling for it all I get are some Maxim components.  If I look at google images I get an assortment of SMD and DIP package pictures that bear no resemblance to one another.

Is there a comprehensive list of component packages (cross-provider) around anywhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whereas most packages are used by several manufacturers, \$\mu\$MAX seems to be a package solely used by Maxim. It's an 8 pin SMT package, about as wide as an SO-8, but just 3mm long instead of the 5mm of an SO-8. This is achieved by using a 0.65mm pitch instead of 1.27mm.
Other manufacturers also go to ever smaller packages, but most often choose for leadless packages like DFN (Dual Flat No Leads).

[image]

---

Intersil has [this list](http://www.intersil.com/design/packages/) of packages.
NXP has [this list](http://www.nxp.com/package/).

Unfortunately my experience is that recommended footprints for a certain package aren't always consistent between manufacturers.

Comment: Looks like yet another reason to avoid Maxim parts.  This one is guaranteed to have no substitutes if Maxim is the only one using this package.  I expect it has a unusually high unobtanium content.

Comment: Why can't they just all stick to a standard instead of each manufacturer making up their own packages???

Comment: @Matt - they mostly do, this is an exception. There are dozens of package types to choose from, so this looks rather pig-headed.

Comment: uMax is just maxim's name for TSOP/SSOP - Where is the problem here?

Comment: @Fake - I haven't compared them parameter by parameter, but if that's right it's even worse. If you follow a standard but name it differently you're only confusing the customer, and you risk that they will react like Olin. (Are there 8-pin versions of TSOP?)

Comment: I never said it was a *good* idea, but IIRC, I have used these with footprints from a standard 0.65 mm pitch TSOP library. I think maxim is claiming it's thinner (in height) then standard TSOP, or something. Basically, it's just stupid.

Comment: Every manufacturer uses its own nomenclature for *something*. NXP calls sot-23 6-lead 'TSMT', some people call QFN and DFN 'LFCSP' or other stuf... this is nothing special or spectacular and not at all a reason to avoid maxim. A much better to avoid maxim is availability and second sourceability.

Comment: μMAX is not TSOP/SSOP as some comments propose. It is a μSOP (MSOP, micro-SOP) - Maxim even specifies that in datasheets: on "package information" pages there is always a xL uMAX/uSOP specification present.

Comment: While looking at the land pattern which Maxim supply for their μMAX 10-pin land pattern I noticed that "MOONLORD MANALO" made changes to the document - a nice believable engineer's name to add to the annoying custom package name! [Maxim document 90-0330](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/land_patterns/90-0330.PDF)

Answer (score 14):

[image]μMAX packages (Maxim uses 8-pin and 10-pin versions of this package) seems (by PCB footprint at least) the same as μSOP aka MSOP aka micro-SOP packages.

This is specified on "Package Information" of the datasheets, where there is always 8L (or 10L) uMAX/uSOP specification present.

Comment: "MSOP" was the kicker for me. Same as "MSOP-8-1EP" in Kicad. Thanks for saving me from drawing another footprint!

Answer (score 4):

Comprehensive list of maxim packages here:

http://www.maxim-ic.com/design/packaging/

Comment: Most important information here.

Answer (score 2):

Just download pdf datasheet for component of interest, and in the end there will be images of all packages with exact geometric sizes & pin locations.

Comment: Recommended footprints, which are as important, are usually not included in the datasheet, but in a more general document. Often harder to find :-(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, µMAX is Maxim's idiotic name for the standard TSOP package.

They certainly fit on the TSOP footprint from the Altium Designer software, anyways.

An 8-pin µMAX is pretty much identical to a standard 3*3 mm body TSOP part.

Comment: TSOP ≠ µSOP !!!

Comment: @minexew - µSOP ≠ µMAX. What's your point?

Comment: But µMAX *is* µSOP. See for example the annotation in https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/package_dwgs/21-0036.PDF